# Access table object based on current paragraph

Tags: vba, ms-word, paragraph

I am iterating through all paragraphs in a document and want to identify their indent level. While this works most of the time using Paragraph.Format.LeftIndent, it does not work for paragraphs within tables. In particular in cases when the paragraph itself is not indented but the table has a left indent.

Is there any way to navigate from the currelty selected paragraph to the table where it is located in? I know there is the property "wdWithInTable" but this is not enough for me because I need the Table object to check its LeftIndent property.

Answer (score 0):

Go get table from current selection use this logic:

```
Sub GetTable()

    Dim currentTable As Table

    Set currentTable = Selection.Tables(1)
    'test purpose only
    Debug.Print currentTable.Rows.Count, currentTable.Columns.Count

    'and to get table indention try with this
    Debug.Print currentTable.Range.ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent

End Sub
```